Rational functions correspond to splitting fields?
I came across this nice exposition of Galois correspondence purely through the fundamental theorem on symmetric polynomials:
THE FUNDAMENTAL THEOREM ON SYMMETRIC POLYNOMIALS: HISTORY’S FIRST WHIFF OF GALOIS THEORY
Towards the end of the article, after Theorem $6$,$7$,$8$ and Galois' Proposition I, the author says
// If you have studied Galois theory, this formulation may feel unfamiliar to you. To see that it is really the same thing you have seen before, consider that the set of quantities that are rational functions of $\sigma_1,...,\sigma_n$ forms a field ($f$’s coefficient field); similarly for the set of quantities that are rational functions of $x_1,..., x_n$ ($f$’s splitting field). The set of rational functions of $\sigma_1,... ,\sigma_n,U,V,...$ is some extension of the coefficient field contained in the splitting field. //
If the coefficients of the polynomial are defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, I get the rational functions of $\sigma_1,...\sigma_n$ will still be $\mathbb{Q}$ and hence $f$'s coefficient field. But how does the rational functions of $x_1,...x_n$ correspond to $f$'s splitting field and $\sigma_1,... ,\sigma_n,U,V,...$ correspond to the field extension?
Thanks.
